# Коммерческое использование GitLab

Tags: gitlab, лицензирование

В крупной компании у меня и моих коллег есть боль: безобразное количество дубликатов прошивок и проектов в разных папках. Из данного положения я нашел выход, GitLab + GitHub Desktop. После разговоров с службой безопасности стало ясно, что у ПО должна быть поддержка от поставщика, по этой причине в нашей компании с OpenSource не оч.

Вопрос: Что купить у GitLab, чтобы GitLab можно было развернуть на своих серверах и иметь поддержку. Хоть какую-нибудь

Comment: P.S. Я понимаю, что вопрос не относится к программированию, хотя-бы скажите куда его спросить

Comment: Посмотрите на использование TortoiseGit. За время работы в нашей команде он показал себя очень хорошо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам вот это нужно [цены](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/#self-managed), 4 доллара на человека норм цена вроде

Comment: Точно, Next business day Support, прошу прощения, черт его знает куда смотрел:)